# django forms add blank choice for a IntegerField

Tags: django, forms, null

I am trying to add a "null" choice to my form choices, since the field is not required.
Now for char fields I could go for a blank and work around that later, but this wont work for an integer field.

My question, how can I add a Null choice for both my CharField and IntegerField

My choices:

```
LIGHT = 0
MEDIUM = 1
HEAVY = 2
ARMORTYPES = (
    (LIGHT, 'Light'),
    (MEDIUM, 'Medium'),
    (HEAVY, 'Heavy'),
)
```

my model:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=63, unique=True)
    flavor = models.TextField()
    price = models.IntegerField()
    weight = models.FloatField()
    armor_proficiency = models.IntegerField(choices=ARMORTYPES, null=True)
    (some more fields)
```

form:

```
class ItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(help_text="name of the item")
    flavor = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea, help_text="short description")
    price = forms.IntegerField(help_text="its market price")
    weight = forms.FloatField(help_text="weight of the item")

    armor_proficiency = forms.ChoiceField(choices=BLANK_CHOICE + ARMORTYPES, required=False, help_text="Some help text")
```

any idea how i could fix this?

Comment: You can add help_text in the model fields directly. No need to override all form fields.

Comment: Add `blank=True` to `armor_prophicency` field and don't override the field in the form. See if it works.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the information, this indeed works, tho now i wonder where to add the help_text to the field so later i could make a mouse over to show it?

Comment: You can set help_text the same way directly on the model field not form field.